# Numpy array of alternating tuples

Tags: python, numpy, tuples, sequence

I am looking for a pythonic/simple way to create a list/sequence of repeating tuples (specifically RGBA values) so that I can apply it to the colors of bars in a matplotlib bar chart.

```
ax.bar(...
       , color=colorlist
   )
```

For example

```
print(colorlist)
array([(0.04, 0.015, 0.02, 1.0),
       (0.8, 0.5, 0.2, 1.0),
       (0.04, 0.015, 0.02, 1.0), ...,
       (0.8, 0.5, 0.2, 1.0),
       (0.04, 0.015, 0.02, 1.0),
       (0.8, 0.5, 0.2, 1.0)], dtype=object)
```

I know the length of `colorlist` (e.g. `N`) I am after. I just can't seem to find a way to create `colorlist`.

I am after a way to arrange the two colors (say `color1` and `color2`) either one immediately followed by the second color (e.g. 0,1,0,1,0,1,..), or some number of one color in a row, then followed another number of the second color, and repeated until the end (0,0,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,..).

EDIT: A worked example;

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

colorlist = np.array(
   ([(0.04, 0.015, 0.02, 1.0)] * 1 + [(0.8, 0.5, 0.2, 1.0)] * 1) * 16, dtype=object
)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
y = np.ones(32)
x = np.linspace(1,32,32)
ax.bar(x, y, facecolor = colorlist)
```

with error

````
ValueError: Invalid RGBA argument: array([[0.04, 0.015, 0.02, 1.0],
       [0.8, 0.5, 0.2, 1.0],
       [0.04, 0.015, 0.02, 1.0],```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like:

```py
colorlist = [(0.04, 0.015, 0.02, 1.0), (0.8, 0.5, 0.2, 1.0)] * 10
```

Gets you 10 repetitions of the list as a list, which you can then cast to an array, as needed?

Similarly, if you want to repeat each colour a known number of times:

```py
colorlist = ([(0.04, 0.015, 0.02, 1.0)] * 2 + [(0.8, 0.5, 0.2, 1.0)] * 3) * 4
```

Gets you 4 repetitions of the first colour twice and the second colour three times.

To cast this to an array of object, for `ax.bar`, you can do something like:

```py
import numpy as np


colorlist = np.array(
    ([(0.04, 0.015, 0.02, 1.0)] * 2 + [(0.8, 0.5, 0.2, 1.0)] * 3) * 4, dtype=object
)
```

Given the specific example code, using `color` instead of `facecolor` works with the original list, even without the cast or the array data type:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

colorlist = ([(0.04, 0.015, 0.02, 1.0)] * 1 + [(0.8, 0.5, 0.2, 1.0)] * 1) * 16

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
y = [1] * 32
x = range(32)
ax.bar(x, y, color=colorlist)
plt.show()
```

However, if preferred, it also works with the `np.array` and either an `object` or `tuple` `dtype`, as well as with the given `numpy` data types. I just wanted to show the result can be achieved with basic Python and `matplotlib` alone.

Comment: Thank you Grismar, this is nice and simple and clear. It does exactly what you said it does. Unfortunatly it doesn't work in the ax.bar( statement, says "ValueError: Invalid RGBA argument:" presumably because it's not in a numpy array with dtype=object?

Comment: I've added a suggestion to cast accordingly; do note that this seems to translate the inner tuples into lists / arrays as well - but I expect that shouldn't be an issue

Comment: Unfortunately the translation from tuple to lists does make a difference to ax.bar. Some error, "Invalid RGBA argument". It's weird, why does it change it from a tuple to a list/array?

Comment: If you provide a more complete example in your code, that you would expect to work, I'd be happy to give it a try

Comment: Thanks Grismar, I appreciate it. I've edited the original question to include an example. It doesn't work for me, presumably because the RGBA values are tuples.